# Slicing by date, using a variable start date

Tags: pandas, slice

I trying to slice according to a date column (which is calculated based on the index), and only cumulative summing based on the Start Date beside it.

Here is a small sample code to copy/run:

```
import numpy
import pandas
data = pandas.DataFrame(
{"Bought" : [1,3,4,6]}, index=pandas.to_datetime(['01-01-2020','02-01-2020','03-01-2020','04-01-2020']))
data['StartDate'] = data.index
data['Cum bought2'] = data.loc[data['StartDate']:]['Bought'].cumsum()
```

It gives me the error "cannot do slice indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers".
If I change the data.loc[data['StartDate']:] to a set value (i.e. '02-01-2020'), then it works fine. But I want the start date to be variable and taken from another column.

**Edit1:** new example. This is close, but the 3rd row shouldn't calculate a value since the Start Date hasn't been reached yet.

```
import numpy
import pandas
data = pandas.DataFrame(
{"Bought" : [1,3,4,6]}, index=pandas.to_datetime(['01-01-2020','02-01-2020','03-01-2020','04-01-2020']))
data['StartDate'] = ['02-01-2020','02-01-2020','04-01-2020','04-01-2020']
data['Cum Bought'] = data.loc[data['StartDate'].iloc[0]:]['Bought'].cumsum()
```

**Edit2:** Also, any idea how to resolve if there are pandas.NaT in the Start Date? I don't want to delete those rows completely, just treat them as zero in calculations.

```
import numpy
import pandas
data = pandas.DataFrame(
{"Bought" : [1,3,4,6]}, index=pandas.to_datetime(['01-01-2020','02-01-2020','03-01-2020','04-01-2020']))
data['StartDate'] = [pandas.NaT,'02-01-2020','04-01-2020','04-01-2020']
data['Cum Bought'] = data.loc[data['StartDate'].iloc[0]:]['Bought'].cumsum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to index with a Series as bound of a slice, which doesn't make sense. You need **one value**. `data.loc[data['StartDate'].iloc[0]:]` or `data.loc[data['StartDate'].min():]` would work.

In your case, you should probably just use:

```
data['Cum bought2'] = data['Bought'].cumsum()
```

Or if you're not sure that the dates are sorted:

```
data['Cum bought2'] = data['Bought'].sort_index().cumsum()
```

Output:

```
            Bought  StartDate  Cum bought2
2020-01-01       1 2020-01-01            1
2020-02-01       3 2020-02-01            4
2020-03-01       4 2020-03-01            8
2020-04-01       6 2020-04-01           14
```

Comment: Basically, at each row, I want the Cum Bought column to start accumulating only based on the the "Start Date" beside, and ending on date of the current row. Hence it should show nothing if the Start Date hasn't been reached yet.  Also, if NaT is in the date, how could I resolve? (I added this NaT scenario to my post).

Comment: Do you mean that you want a `shift`? `data['Cum bought2'] = data['Bought'].cumsum().shift()`

Comment: Basically, if the corresponding Start Date shows 2020-01-02 and today (i.e. current row) is 2020-01-03, then it should only cumsum Jan 2 and Jan 3. If the Start Date shows 2020-01-04, then the corresponding row should only cumsum Jan 4th until the current row's date.

Comment: Oh I see why i'm getting an error when the first value is NaT, because the "data['StartDate'].iloc[0]" will always reference that NaT. Somehow i'm wondering if I can make the Start Date dynamic and reference the adjacent cell.

Comment: Can you please improve your example in the question?

Comment: Thanks, pasted a couple codes above. 1)Works ok, except the third row shouldn't calculate. 2)How to resolve if there are NaTs, without removing all NaTs?